# with .htaccess file using sub-directory with root to re-write url in PHP and XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, url-rewriting, xampp

I am running XAMPP Server V. 3.2.1 on my windows.
I have .htaccess file having the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?cmd=$1&caseSno=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /?cmd=$1 [NC,L]
```

It working fine for me with two parameters in url and can rewrite my

```
?cmd=page_name&id=34
```

like this

```
localhost/home/34
```

Now, i am trying to access my other pages which are situated in subdirectory. structure of my directory is here:

```
Please view the following image for directory structure
```

[image]

Please help me in this i am beginner with .htaccess

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule inside `/court_Admin/courtUsers/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /court_Admin/courtUsers/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ ?cmd=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: should i need to put the same .htaccess file within each sub-directory  and will need to change line for base rewrite like : RewriteBase /court_Admin/recordRoom/ ?

Comment: Yes that's correct, this will be cleaner approach rather than stuffing all the rules in one file.